# How to flatten a Future in scala - "val _2flat: Future[Option[Future[List[Long]]]]

Tags: scala, nested, future

I have this data:

```
val _2BeFlat: Future[Option[Future[List[Long]]]] = ...
```

And I need:

```
val flat: Future[Option[List[Long]]] = ...
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```scala
val _2BeFlat: Future[Option[Future[List[Long]]]] = _

val flat: Future[Option[List[Long]]] = _2BeFlat.flatMap {
  _ match {
    case None => Future.successful(None)
    case Some(future) => future.map(Some(_))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! (and since it looks like easy 4 u) can you help converting this also "val futureRes: Future[Option[Future[List[Array[Long]]]]]" to "Future[Option[List[Long]]]"

Comment: Simply replace the `case Some(future) =>` line with `case Some(future) => future.map(ls => Some(ls.flatMap(_.toList)))`

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.